# Vuex mutations and actions not working

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I'm new to Vue and Vuex and I'm trying to figure out how to mutate data in the store.

Currently in my State the default username is 'default' and I want to change it to 'otto', later ill grab this information from the database. But for the purpose of understanding I'm just trying to get this to work.

At this point the component is loaded correctly, and it displays 'default'. There are no errors present.

The store.js:

```
// store.js 
export default {
    state: {
        username: 'default'
    },
    getters: {
    },
    mutations: {
        changeUsername (state) {
            state.username = 'otto'
        }
    },
    actions: {
        changeUsername (context) {
            context.commit('changeUsername')
        }
    }
}
```

The vue file:

```
// Basic.vue
<template>
    <div>
        <p>{{ username }}</p>

    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import { mapState } from 'vuex';
    import { mapMutations } from 'vuex';
    import { mapActions } from 'vuex';


    export default {
        name: "basic",

        computed: {
            ...mapState([
                'username'
            ])
        },
        methods: {
            ...mapMutations([
                'changeUsername'
            ]),
            ...mapActions([
                'changeUsername'
            ])
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: where do you call the mutation/action?

Comment: @ThomasKleßen I'm not sure where to call the mutation/action, and how..

Answer (score 1):

Don't include your mutation, as it will be called by your action. And call the action on a button click for instance:

The store:

```
// store.js 
export default {
    state: {
        username: 'default'
    },
    getters: {
        username: state => state.username
    },
    mutations: {
        setUsername (state) {
            state.username = 'otto'
        }
    },
    actions: {
        updateUsername (context) {
            context.commit('setUsername ')
        }
    }
}
```

The component:

```
// Basic.vue
<template>
    <div>
        <p>{{ username }}</p>
        <button @click="updateUsername">Change!</button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "basic",

        computed: {
            username() {
                return this.$store.getters.username
            }
        },
        methods: {
            updateUsername() {
                this.$store.dispatch('updateUsername')
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Additionnal advice:** be carefull when naming your mutations and actions. You don't want them to have the same name to avoid unwanted behaviors. I usually name my mutation `setXXXX` and my action `getXXX` or `patchXXX` depending of what the request does.

[Working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2xodr86k/10/)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! What do you recommend with regard to naming conventions? So that I know the mutation and actions are related but don't have the same name?

Comment: I seem to be running into this error when clicking on a button -->            Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined at VueComponent.mappedAction (app.js:1267) at invoker (app.js:39323) at HTMLButtonElement.fn._withTask.fn._withTask (app.js:39122)

Comment: Of course... actions must be called through a `dispatch`. Look at my edit and my example. I also added a getter in the store to not access the state directly.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for the help, now I'm getting this output when changing all the code accordingly, username now outputs: "function username(state) { return state.username; }" Furthermore when I change the getter to                 "return this.$store.state.username", it does work. However then when I click the button I get an error: "Uncaught TypeError: this.$store.dispatch is not a function"

Comment: You probably have an issue with your store initialization/inclusion if dispatch is not available. Try to come back to a very basic working situation to see where it fails.

Answer (score 0):

```
<template>
    <div>
        <p @click="changeUsername">{{ username }}</p>

    </div>
</template>
```

You could change the username if the user clicks at the p tag like that.

Comment: Thanks, however now I'm running into the following error when clicking the button or p tag.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
    at VueComponent.mappedAction (app.js:1267)
    at invoker (app.js:39323)
    at HTMLButtonElement.fn._withTask.fn._withTask (app.js:39122)